# How can I change alignment of header QTreeView PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I want to change alignment of header of QTreeView to the center or right side.. I google it but the answers were only for C++  :D I didn't understand..

I want to change (TITLES) Header to center or right side look at this:
https://imgur.com/Jvfdcgn

Thank for help.

```
class My(QWidget,myui):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(QWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dataView=QTreeView()
        self.model=self.createModel(self)
        self.dataView.setModel(self.model)


    def information(self,name):
        self.addData(self.model,name)

    def createModel(self,parent):
        model=QStandardItemModel(0,1,parent)
        model.setHeaderData(self.TITLE,Qt.Horizontal,'TITLES') # I want to change 'TITLES' to the center or right side.

        return model

    def addData(self,model,TITLE):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0,self.TITLE),TITLE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the [default alignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#defaultAlignment-prop) of the header.
A QTableView or QTableWidget have both an `horizontalHeader()` and `verticalHeader()`, but since a QTreeView/QTreeWidget only has the horizontal header, the function is simply `header()`.

```
self.dataView.header().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

The vertical alignment is not usually necessary, I've just added it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set alignment for specific column:

```
column = 2
self.dataView.headerItem().setTextAlignment(column, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Comment: I did ,but i could not because of  reputation less than 15.. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

With PySide2 and a QTableview, this works:

```
self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 3, self)
self.table.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
```

I don't have a working PyQt5/QTreeView example to see if it is similar; but maybe this is enough to help you?

Comment: Thank u for reply, but its different because QTreeView has no attribute 'horizontalHeader'.

Comment: It has a QHeaderView instead, which has a setDefaultAlignment. Isn't that working?